# Radiometry, understanding notation

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation

I'm watching the following video:

https://youtu.be/gLfYTP4F23g?t=21m51s

Where essentially the two following definitions are given:

Irradiance:

$$
E = \frac{d\Phi}{dA}
$$

where $\Phi$ is the flux, measured in watts, and $A$ is the incident area, therefore the area is expressed as $Watts/{m^2}$.

The definition of radiance

$$
L = \frac{d^2 \Phi}{d \omega dAcos(\theta)}
$$

is similar, except for the fact that solid angle and, area projections are taken into account, the unit of measure is $Watts/(steradiant\cdot m^2)$.
I'm a bit confused how differential are used  in the notation however, because at some point the following relationship is derived between $L$ and $E$

$$
L d \omega cos(\theta) = E.
$$

Which doesn't make sense to me, it would make sense to me having

$$
L d \omega cos(\theta) = dE
$$

Is there anything wrong? Is there a more rigorous way to derive the equality?